# Is it faster to write one line for all margin sides in css?

Tags: css, margin, dimension

I always try to use the single-line approach to declare e.g. the margin of an element.

```
margin: <margin-top> || <margin-right> || <margin-bottom> || <margin-left>
```

I was wondering if this actually runs faster than the four-line approach.

```
margin-top: <margin-top>;
margin-right: <margin-right>
margin-botttom: <margin-bottom>
margin-left: <margin-left>
```

Comment: All browsers are not created equally, but this probably doesn't matter at all. You should write the code that you find most readable first, and worry about performance if you actually perceive a performance issue.

Comment: This is somewhat akin to asking what type of sandals you should wear to get the best acceleration from putting your foot down on the pedal in your FORD C-MAX

Answer (score 3):

you can use shorthand property

```
Ex: margin: top right bottom left;
In place of top,right,bottom,left you will give values.
```